# ImagePicker.platform shows warning - Flutter

Tags: flutter, compiler-warnings, imagepicker

I am using the following code to pick an image from user's gallery.

```
Future getImageFromGallery(BuildContext context) async {
    await ImagePicker.platform()
        .pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery)
        .then((image) {
      if (image != null) {
        _cropImage(image, context);
      }
    });
  }
```

I am getting the following warning.

```
The member 'platform' can only be used within 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart' or a test.
```

I'm not sure what the warning means. I tried looking it up but couldn't figure out the solution to resolve this warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just change the code

```
ImagePicker.platform().pickImage(...)
```

to

```
ImagePicker().pickImage(...)
```

so

```
Future getImageFromGallery(BuildContext context) async {
    await ImagePicker()
      .pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery)
      .then((image) {
      if (image != null) {
         _cropImage(image, context);
      }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try below code hope its help to you

Declare **File** type form `dart.io` package

```
File? imagePicked;
```

Create Function for pick up the image

```
void gallaryImage() async {
    final picker = ImagePicker();
    final pickedImage = await picker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
    );
    final pickedImageFile = File(pickedImage!.path);
    setState(() {
      imagePicked = pickedImageFile;
    });
  }
```

Create your Widget

```
TextButton(
      onPressed: gallaryImage,
      child: Text(
      'Gallery',
      style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
       ),
     ),
    ),
```