# In flutter when camera is opened from image picker the app "Lost connection to device."

Tags: android, flutter, dart

When I go through opening up the camera to set profile image using image picker, the app crashes and I lost connection to device

:[image]

**When pick up image from gallery its working fine,**

> my pubspec.yaml

```
  name: flutterapp
description: A new Flutter project.

# Prevent accidental publishing to pub.dev.
publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  
  connectivity: ^3.0.6
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
 
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  font_awesome_flutter: 
  geolocator: ^7.7.0
  http: ^0.13.4
  
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+3
  local_auth: ^1.1.8
  path_provider: ^2.0.5
  pdf: ^3.6.0
  permission_handler: ^8.2.5
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.8
  

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  
  # Enable generation of localized Strings from arb files.
  generate: true

  assets:
    # Add assets from the images directory to the application.
    - assets/
```

Comment: try my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69571252/13997210) hope its helpful to you. for Image picker

Comment: same code i used and its working fine when i pick image from gallery, but when i try to use camera it lost its connection

Comment: please check my below answer hope its helpful to you. Its working for me

Answer (score 5):

If you are using an iOS device then you have to add permission for image picking. Add these line in your info.plist file.

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Access to take a photo by camera</string>
<key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
<string>Access to pick a photo</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Access to pick a photo</string>
```

Comment: What's the use of NSAppleMusicUsageDescription?

Comment: A message that tells the user why the app is requesting access to the user’s media library. 

for more details check out this 

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapplemusicusagedescription?changes=latest_major&language=objc_3

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and i check the state of memory, and yes, this case happen beacuse the memory Ram of the device is full and close the task automaticly, so .

1. I check the state memory in the observatory of flutter, you press "Ctrl + Shift + P" when the aplication is running and write observatory for see the state of memory  of the device [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y89Ah.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gauaQ.png)
2. I defined the cacheHeight and cacheWidth with the atribbute of Image.file widget and i modified the filterQuality atributte in none:

> Image.file(
> File(path),
> filterQuality: FilterQuality.none,
> cacheHeight: 66,
> cacheWidth: 50,
> )

Excuseme for my english.

Answer (score 1):

Run your code on another device then it can work properly.
The first time I used 'Xiaomi Note 7 pro' but shows the same error after run the code on another device its work properly. Also, you can update the version of your image_picker.

It's worked for me and I used:

image_picker: ^0.8.4+1

Flutter version: 2.2.3

```
 void _pickImageCamera() async {
final picker = ImagePicker();
final pickedImage =
await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, imageQuality: 90);
final pickedImageFile = File(pickedImage!.path);
setState(() {
  _pickedImage = pickedImageFile;
});
Navigator.pop(context); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. In below code I used picked image using Camera as well as Gallery

Declare **File** type form `dart.io` package

```
File? imagePicked;
```

> Create Function for pick up the image from **Gallery**

```
void gallaryImage() async {
    final picker = ImagePicker();
    final pickedImage = await picker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
    );
    final pickedImageFile = File(pickedImage!.path);
    setState(() {
      imagePicked = pickedImageFile;
    });
  }
```

> Create Function for pick up the image from **Camera**

```
void cameraImage() async {
    final picker = ImagePicker();
    final pickedImage = await picker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
    );
    final pickedImageFile = File(pickedImage!.path);
    setState(() {
      imagePicked = pickedImageFile;
    });
  }
```

> Create your Widget

```
 Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        TextButton.icon(
          onPressed: cameraImage,
          label: Text(
            'Camera',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.camera,
          ),
        ),
        TextButton.icon(
          onPressed: gallaryImage,
          label: Text(
            'Gallery',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          icon: Icon(Icons.image),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same issue and since my app doesn't open to the same screen from where it got crashed, I had to follow the below official approach

https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera