# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'File' of 'function result' in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on flutter to upload images to the **SQL server** but there is a error :

> type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'File' of 'function result'

here is how I am initialising the file:

```
late File _image;

final picker=ImagePicker();

Future choiceImage() async{
 var pickedImage= await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
 setState(() {

  _image=File(pickedImage!.path);
});
}
 Future choice2Image() async{
   var pickedImage= await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  setState(() {
  _image=File(pickedImage!.path);
});
 }
```

and getting this image by :

```
var pic =await http.MultipartFile.fromPath("image", _image.path);
```

and dont know what is the issue ?

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69973004/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69807439/13997210) hope its helpful to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImagePicker` can return a `null` value if you don't pick any image from the image picker sheet. Therefore, you need to handle `null` values.

This is what you can do.

```
File? _image;

final picker=ImagePicker();

Future choiceImage() async{
 var pickedImage= await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
   if(pickedImage!=null)
     {
       setState(() 
          {
           _image=File(pickedImage!.path);
         });
      }
    }
```

Comment: Checking null before setting picked image path is a correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `late File _image;`
you can try using:

```
File? _image;
```

Do not forget to check `null` before using `_image` variable further:

```
if(_image!=null){
    // further code statements will be here...

}
```

Comment: after using this i am getting an error " null check operator used on null value"

Comment: you might use ```File? _image``` only.

Comment: you mean only File? _image without semicolon ";"

Comment: no no,edited the answer.