# The value 'null' can't be returned from a function with return type 'Widget' because 'Widget' is not nullable

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

**what'd I miss ?** is it because  dart version  or other things ,

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.1 <3.0.0"
```

**1.** error

> Error: The value 'null' can't be returned from a function with return
> type 'Widget' because 'Widget' is not nullable.
>
> - 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart'

// Alertdialog box showing

```
showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      content: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 22.0, bottom: 22),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Text(
                "Would you like to get latest updates and notifications?",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 24),
            Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    snackBarText = "You will not recive notifications.";
                  });
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(new MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => null));
                },
                child: Text(
                  "DENY",
                  style:
                      TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16, height: 1.2),
                ),
                color: Colors.purple,
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    snackBarText = "You will recive notifications.";
                  });
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(new MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => null));
                },
                child: Text(
                  "ALLOW",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.purple, fontSize: 16, height: 1.2),
                ),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    side: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.purple)),
                color: Colors.white,
              )
            ])
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }
```

**2.**error

> lib/ua_Screens.dart:29:8: Error: Field '_image' should be initialized
> because its type 'File' doesn't allow null.
>
> - 'File' is from 'dart:io'.   File _image;
>   ^^^^^^

```
File _image;
Future get_image() async {
    final image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
  }
```

Comment: In the first question, if you are using alert dialog inside widget, convert the widget to function, so you could return null from the function if needed, widget is not nullable as the error shows

Comment: In the second question. according to the error just initialize the File before using it like ;                 


  File _image=File('');

Answer (score 1):

I think you write wrong code, try below code hope its help to used. and one thing dont used `FlatButton` used `TextButton` because `FlatButton` is depriciated by flutter.

Refer [`TextButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton-class.html)

Your Alert Dialog function:

```
showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      content: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 22.0, bottom: 22),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Text(
                "Would you like to get latest updates and notifications?",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 24),
            Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {});
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(new MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => null));
                },
                child: Text(
                  "DENY",
                  style:
                      TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16, height: 1.2),
                ),
                color: Colors.purple,
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {});
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(new MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => null));
                },
                child: Text(
                  "ALLOW",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.purple, fontSize: 16, height: 1.2),
                ),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    side: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.purple)),
                color: Colors.white,
              )
            ])
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Your Widget:

```
ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return showAlertDialog(context);
                },
              );
            },
            child: Text('Pressed Me'),
          ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Your alert dialog-> [image]

Your Second error refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69571252/13997210) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69973004/13997210)