# How to work with image upload in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

This is a Flutter project made with Getx. I'm trying to implement an image upload, but I'm not getting it, and the strange thing is that the application doesn't generate error messages. With the error messages I could even deal with. The image below will explain the functionality.

[image]

There is one detail that needs to be mentioned. Every time I run the application the application doesn't capture the session, it's weird, it doesn't make sense.

[image]

It could be that some error in the code and I'm not noticing that's why you need help identifying where the problem is.

**Repository**

```
Future<String?> sendImage(String? image) async {
    final formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "": await MultipartFile.fromFile((image!), filename: image),
    });

    final response = await dio.post(
      AppConstants.apiUploadImage,
      data: formData,
    );
    return response.data;
  }

  Future<UserProfile> uploadProfile({
    String? image,
  }) async {
    dio.options.headers['Cookie'] = 'ASP.NET_SessionId=${user.sessionID}';
    dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data;';
    String? imageResponse;

    if (image != null && image != '') {
      imageResponse = await sendImage(image);
    }

    final response = await dio.get(
      AppConstants.apiUploadImageProfile,
      queryParameters: {
        'sessionId': user.sessionID,
        'CodUser': user.codUser,
        'FilePicture': imageResponse?.substring(47) ?? '',
      },
    );

    return UserProfile.fromJson(response.data);

  }
```

**Controller**

```
Future<UserProfile> updateImageProfile(String? image) async {
    final post = await repository.uploadProfile(
      image: image,
    );
    return post;
  }
```

**Page**

```
 onTap: () {
        showModalBottomSheet(
          isScrollControlled: true,
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(32),
              topRight: Radius.circular(32),
            ),
          ),
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => ImageProfileWidget(),
        );
      },
```

**ImageProfileWidget**

```
class ImageProfileWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImageProfileWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ImageProfileWidget> createState() => _ImageProfileWidgetState();
}


class _ImageProfileWidgetState extends State<ImageProfileWidget>
    with NotifierLoadingMixin {

    final HomeController controller = GetInstance().find();
    final galeryController = SelectImageFileController();
    final cameraController = CaptureCameraImageController();
    final compressionController = CompressImageController();

    @override
    late final loadingNotifier = compressionController;

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();

      galeryController.addListener(() async {
        final filePath = galeryController.value;
        final valueIsNull = filePath != null;

        if (valueIsNull) {
          final fileBytes = await File(filePath).readAsBytes();
          await compressionController.compressImage(fileBytes, filePath);
        }
      });

      cameraController.addListener(() async {
        final filePath = cameraController.value;
        if (filePath != null) {
          final fileBytes = await File(filePath).readAsBytes();
          await compressionController.compressImage(fileBytes, filePath);
        }
      });

      void _cropImage(filePath) async {
        await ImageCropper().cropImage(
            sourcePath: filePath, maxHeight: 1080, maxWidth: 1080);
        await controller.updateImageProfile(
            controller.imagePath);
      }


      compressionController.addListener(() {
        final compressedFilePath = compressionController.value.filePath;

        if (compressedFilePath != null) {
          _cropImage(compressedFilePath);
          controller.selectImage(compressedFilePath);
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        }
      });
    }


    @override
    void dispose() {
      super.dispose();
      galeryController.dispose();
      cameraController.dispose();
      compressionController.dispose();
    }


    @override
    Widget loadingBuilder(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 15, 10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            const CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(AppColors.primary),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 15),
            Text("Comprimindo imagem",
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .bodyText1
                    ?.copyWith(color: AppColors.primary)),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 28),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30, top: 16),
              color: const Color(0XFFC4C4C4),
              height: 6,
              width: 54,
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
              title: const Text('Câmera'),
              onTap: cameraController.capture,
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.image),
              title: const Text('Galeria'),
              onTap: galeryController.onSelectFilePressed,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

}
```

The section of this Widget's class that performs the operation.

[image]

Comment: Try my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69807439/13997210) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69571252/13997210) for image picker hope its help to you.